# How do I wake up the Snorlax that's in Pokemon village?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I went to the Snorlax in Pokemon village and I've been told that there's a hidden door under the Snorlax and I've been wondering how do you wake up that Snorlax

Comment: There's also a Mew hidden under the truck in Pokémon Red/Blue (note: both these claims are false).

Answer (score 7):

Best I can tell that snorlax is merely for decoration. Only the Snorlax on the road with the daycare can be woken and caught. [Others have reported no success in doing anything with the snorlax](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/173815/how-can-you-wake-up-the-snorlax-in-pokemon-village-in-pokemon).